# Prompts for Custom Functions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

When you use an excel function say average(..) once you type "=average( " in a cell excel prompts you with what the function is expecting. Is there a way to create these same type of prompts for a custom function?

[image]

Have not found any microsoft info or guides on this